# Remain Input Field Contents When Error Occurs Upon Submission or After Refreshing Page

Tags: php, jquery, forms, yii

I have a form where user can input Start and End Dates. I used a date picker for this. I want that when the user refreshes the page or when the user submitted the form but is redirected to the same page because of an error, those inputted Start and End Dates should remain in place. In my case, the inputted data disappear upon refresh or when error occurs upon submission.

Here's my view:

```
<div class="info">
   <label class="col-lg-2 form-label"><b>Start Date</b></label>
      <div class="col-lg-4" >
         <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', 
                         array('name' => 'FormDetails_date_fr',
                               'options' => array(
                               'showAnim' => 'blind',
                               'beforeShowDay' => 'js:$.datepicker.noWeekends',
                               'minDate' => 'date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day")',
                               'changeMonth' => true,
                               'changeYear' => true,
                               'dateFormat' => 'yy-mm-dd',
                                            ),
                               'htmlOptions' => array(
                               'class' => 'form-control A',
                               //'id' =>'A',
                                ),
                           )); ?>
      </div>
</div>

<div class="info">
   <label class="col-lg-2 form-label"><b>Start Date</b></label>
      <div class="col-lg-4" >
         <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', 
                         array('name' => 'FormDetails_date_to',
                               'options' => array(
                               'showAnim' => 'blind',
                               'beforeShowDay' => 'js:$.datepicker.noWeekends',
                               'minDate' => 'date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day")',
                               'changeMonth' => true,
                               'changeYear' => true,
                               'dateFormat' => 'yy-mm-dd',
                                            ),
                               'htmlOptions' => array(
                               'class' => 'form-control C',
                               //'id' =>'A',
                                ),
                           )); ?>
      </div>
</div>
```

I am using Yii 1.1 PHP Framework.
Any ideas anyone? Please help.

Comment: Do not these options  `'showAnim' => 'blind',
                               'beforeShowDay' => 'js:$.datepicker.noWeekends',` frustrate inputted data to remain in form? Would you try to comment them and try it over?

Comment: hi @IgorSavinkin. I tried but still not working. :(

Answer (score 0):

I've checked `zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker` functionality. Seems to me it is not designed for retaining inputted value.

### Bypass solution might be:

1. Have an ajax call upon value input by user to save inputted value somewhere (as a model attribute or an app parameter or session parameter). So put something like this (taken from Select2 example) in the datepicker config:

   'htmlOptions'=>array( 
           'onChange'=>CHtml::ajax(array('type'=>'POST',
           'url'=>'/',
           'data'=>'js:this.value',)),
       ),
2. In the datapicker config you define `value` based on saved parameter:

   $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', 
                        array('name' => 'FormDetails_date_to',
                           'value'=>$model->attributeName, 
                     // 'value'=>Yii->app()->params['datepickerTempValue'],

thus a saved value will be inserted upon page reload.